# virtualbox, host-only network, dhcp ack, router missing

Tags: router, virtualbox, dhcp-server

I'm using a VirtualBox VM with a host-only adapter. On the host-OS I have enabled IPv4 forwarding and configured iptables' FORWARD chain to allow outgoing NEW connections from vboxnet0 to wlan0 and ESTABLISHED/RELATED connections in the opposite direction.

I want to achieve that the guest-VMs can access the internet (via host-OS WLAN-NIC), but programs running on the host-OS shall be blocked from the internet (by corresponding blocking rules in the iptables' INPUT and OUTPUT chains).

In principle this scenario works fine. There is only one little annoying problem with DHCP when VirtualBox is used (KVM/QEMU does not have this problem): The DHCP ACK packet from the VirtualBox internal DHCP server to the guest-VM does not contain the "Router" parameter (KVM's DHCP ACK contains it) to define the default gateway for the guest-VM, which should be 192.168.56.1 (IP address of vboxnet0).

So I have to manually configure the default gateway in my guest-OS. And because the guest-OS is a read-only live-distribution, I have to do it at every boot, which is annoying.

Is there a way to make the VirtualBox internal DHCP server send the router parameter in its DHCP ACK packet? Or some other solution?